# Как проверить, есть ли в тексте сообщения пользователя определенные слова в телеграм боте?

Tags: javascript

Телеграм бот на node-telegram-bot-api. Нужно проверить, есть ли в тексте сообщения, от пользователя, определенные слова и если их нет, то отправлять сообщение. Я вынес эти слова в массив и не совсем понимаю как сделать проверку.

```
bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
    const text = msg.text.toLowerCase()
    const chatId = msg.chat.id
    const options = ['текст один', 'текст два', 'текст три']
    
    if (!text.includes(options)) {
      bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'anything')
    }
}
```

Comment: вам нужны базовые знания языка. читайте https://learn.javascript.ru/string и https://learn.javascript.ru/array

Comment: @nörbörnën при чем тут базовые знания. msg.text это сам по себе не массив, мне нужно найти совпадения не в массиве элементов. Тут не работает не includes, не indexOf, не match и даже если преобразовать массив в строку. Документация на node-telegram-bot-api, не на столько обширная. И если у вас есть базовые знания, почему бы вам просто не помочь с решением?

Comment: зато options массив. options.some()

Comment: регулярки решают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так (см. [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)):

```js
bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
    const text = msg.text.toLowerCase()
    const chatId = msg.chat.id
    const options = ['текст один', 'текст два', 'текст три']
    
    if (!options.some(option => text.includes(option))) {
      bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'anything')
    }
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 2):

Это пример с регулярными выражениями, конструктор регулярок можно усложнить например для разных склонений в русском языке и т.п.

```js
const words = ['текст один', 'текст два', 'текст три'];
const re = RegExp(words.join('|'), 'ig');
const result = 'это например текст один или текст два'.match(re);
console.log(result);
```

> [   "текст один",   "текст два" ]